# Serialization to deserialize the order information

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

In my one of the interview, Interviewer gave me the scenario where I am getting a file through the FTP with the order information stored with each field separated by comma. I need to store this information in the object of the class Order using **Serialization**.

File format:
orderId,securityName,Buy/Sell,OrderType,Qty,Price

```
Class Order
{
    int orderId;
    String securityName;
    ....

}
```

I would like to mention here that the file is generated by some other application and we have to use the file generated by that application.  I was confused how would i do that as there was no marshalling done there so how do i unmarshall the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you will be storing the file data into objects using ***deserialization***. The point of the exercise being to recognize that you can implement custom serialization/deserialization of objects by implementing the following methods in your class:

```
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
     throws IOException;

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

In your particular case, you will be implementing the `readObject` method, to read from the comma separated value file, and populating the instance of the object with the values obtained. Something like:

```
class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6730370200519884700L;

    // Instance variables, Constructors, Getters/Setters

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) {
        // obtain data from stream and use
    }
}
```

Quite obviously, ***this is pseudocode***, but it should give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: Thanks Perception. I think this is what the interview must be expecting..

Comment: Complete nonsense from start to finish. An ObjectInputStream is not a CSV file. The readObject() method has an ObjectInputStream argument, not an ObjectOutputStream. You cannot read anything whatsoever from an output stream of any kind. The interviewer specifically stated that the data was to be saved via Serialization, not deserialization, notwithstanding your meaningless statement to the contrary. Is this a joke? -1

Comment: Are you serious? Your entire rant is based off an obvious typo (please re-read the signatures posted a few lines above). This is borderline troll behavior, even for you.

Comment: There's far more wrong here than just one mere typo. You cannot read a CSV file with an ObjectInputStream. You have the entire question back to front. @HardikShah This is most definitely not what the interviewer was expecting.

Comment: @EJP - nowhere in the question or my answer is a CSV file mentioned, the requirement is to recreate an object from a record who's fields are separated by commas.

Comment: @Perception If there is a difference between a CSV file and a file whose records have comma-separated fields, you will have to explain it to me. You will also have to explain how you can use an `ObjectInputSTream` on such a file. I predict you will get a `StreamCorruptedException` on construction. Let me know when you've falsified that prediction, so that we have an agreed empirical basis for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read CSV file to get the list of Order objects.
2. Use serialization to store the wrapper object in file.

Comment: I don't want to store the object back to the file. The question was that can i get the order information into the Order Object using de-serialization process instead of manually performing the file handling operation and then loading the Order object?

Comment: @HardikShah No it wasn't. The question says you are getting a CSV file and have to 'store this information in the object of class Order *by serialization*.' Your own words. De-serialization has nothing to do within.